# Counting Gems on the Ground

Tags: code-golf, string, array

## Counting Gems

### Background

My jewel box just fell down! There're too many gems of different shape on the ground. And your task is to count number of a certain type of gem.

### I/O

- Your code should take two inputs `S` and `G`, which could be a string with newlines, an array of lines, a two-dimensional array of characters, a textfile or in any reasonable format (if so, please state it clearly).
- These two strings will only contain `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ `` (from `0x21` to `0x7E` in ASCII table), space and newlines (binary form depending on your platform).
- In each string, lines are in same length.
- `S` is the gem we want to count. There're two circumstances.

  1. Enclosed and doesn't contain any nested enclosed area. (in example 1/2)
  2. Doesn't contain any enclosed area. (in example 3/4)
- Surrounding spaces are not regarded as a part of the gem.
- `G` is the shape of gems on the ground.
- It is acceptable that your code requires extra input to specify the dimension(s) of `S` and `G`
- It is acceptable that your code take ASCII values as inputs, instead of characters themselves. But you should **not** substitute characters with simpler integers (0,1,2,3). Your program should be able to process characters, or ASCII values.

### Example 1 (Character as input)

Input `S`:

```
+-+  
| +-+
| | |
| | |
| +-+
+-+
```

Input `G`:

```
    +-+       +-+
    | +-+   +-+ |
    | | |   | | |
    | | |   | | |
    | +-+   +-+ |
    +-+       +-+
         +-+     
+---+    | +-+   
|   |    | | |   
|   |    | | |   
|   |    | +-++  
|   |    +-+| +-+
+---+       | | |
            | | |
  +-+       | +-+
  | +-+     +-+  
  | |-|          
  | |-|          
  | +-+          
  +-+
```

Ouptut:

```
2
```

### Example 2 (ASCII value as input)

Input `S`:

```
32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32
32 32 32 32 99 32 99 32
32 32 32 99 32 99 32 99
32 32 32 99 32 32 32 99
32 32 32 99 32 32 32 99
32 32 32 99 32 32 32 99
32 32 32 32 99 32 99 32
32 32 32 32 32 99 32 32
32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32
```

Input `G`:

```
32 99 32 99 32 99 32 99 32 32 99 32
99 32 99 32 99 32 99 32 99 99 32 99
99 32 32 32 99 32 32 32 99 32 32 99
99 99 32 32 99 32 32 32 99 32 32 99
99 32 32 32 99 32 32 32 99 32 32 99
32 99 32 99 32 99 32 99 99 32 99 32
32 32 99 32 32 32 99 32 32 99 32 32
```

Output:

```
1
```

Visualized `S` (32 replaced with --):

```
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- -- -- -- 99 -- 99 --
-- -- -- 99 -- 99 -- 99
-- -- -- 99 -- -- -- 99
-- -- -- 99 -- -- -- 99
-- -- -- 99 -- -- -- 99
-- -- -- -- 99 -- 99 --
-- -- -- -- -- 99 -- --
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Visualized `G`:

```
-- 99 -- 99 -- 99 -- 99 -- -- 99 --
99 -- 99 -- 99 -- 99 -- 99 99 -- 99
99 -- -- -- 99 -- -- -- 99 -- -- 99
99 99 -- -- 99 -- -- -- 99 -- -- 99
99 -- -- -- 99 -- -- -- 99 -- -- 99
-- 99 -- 99 -- 99 -- 99 99 -- 99 --
-- -- 99 -- -- -- 99 -- -- 99 -- --
```

### Example 3 (Not enclosed)

Thanks to @Draco18s

Input `S`

```
AB
```

Input `G`

```
AAB BA CAB
```

Output

```
2
```

### Example 4 (Not enclosed 2D)

Input `S`

```
ABCD
  GE
   F
```

Input `G`

```
ABCD 
BGGED
CDEFE
    F
```

Output

```
1
```

### Remarks

- Only two gems of exact one shape are considered the same.
- Same shape in different directions are not considered the same.
- However, as is described in example I/O, overlapping is possible. Under such circumstances, only complete ones are counted.
- `+`, `-` and `|` in the example have no special meanings. They do not indicate any corner or edge of the shape.
- You may assume input is always valid.
- **You may assume two target gems never share an exactly same edge.**
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- This is a code-golf, so shortest code wins!

Comment: I don't understand the second example, how is `G` contained within `S`?

Comment: @LiefdeWen I made it visualized, you may find `S` in the middle of `G`.

Comment: I think some simpler examples are needed here, such as `S = "AB"`,`G="    AAB BA CAB"`, output = ?

Comment: @Draco18s Thank you, i will add it.

Comment: That simple example really helped understand the desired behavior. Cool

Comment: Imo, this is almost like searching for sub-images within a larger image, but WAY MORE difficult, since we need to first find each sub-images and find the number of matches. lol!

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 303 <del>305</del> <del>326</del> bytes

All optimizations need to be turned off and only work on 32-bit GCC.

```c
#define r(z,k)for(z=0;z<k;z++)
#define c s[i][j]
x,y,o,p,t,i,j;char**s;h(i,j){!((i<0)+(j<0)+i/x+j/y+c-32)?h(i+1,j),h(i-1,j),h(i,j+1),h(i,j-1),c=0:0;}f(w,e,u,v,a,g)char**a,**g;x=w,y=e,s=a;r(o,x)h(o,0),h(o,y-1);r(p,y)h(0,p),h(x-1,p);w=0;r(o,u-x+1)r(p,v-y+1){t=1;r(i,x)r(j,y)t*=!(c*(c-g[i+o][j+p]));w+=t;}}
```

The code uses floodfill to replace surrounding spaces with `\0` and looks for matches while ignoring `\0`.

ungolfed and macros calculated (some letters are different from the golfed version, but logic stays the same):

```c
int x, y, o, p, c, d, t;
char **s, **g;
h(int i, int j) {                             // Floodfill function
    if(i<0 || j<0) return;                    // Boundary detection
    if(i>=x || j>=y) return;
    if(s[i][j] != ' ') return;                // Character detection

    s[i][j] = 0;                              // Replace it with \0
    h(i+1, j);
    h(i-1, j)
    h(i  , j+1);
    h(i  , j-1);
}
f(
    int w,    //1st dimension of S
    int e,    //2nd dimension of S
    int u,    //1st dimension of G
    int v     //2nd dimension of G
    char** i, //Input S
    char** j, //Input G
    );
{
    x=w,y=e,s=i,g=j;
    for(o=0; o<x; o++)                        // Replace all surrounding spaces using floodfill
    {
        h(o, 0);                               
        h(o, y-1);
    }
    for(p=0; p<y; p++)
    {
        h(0,   p);
        h(x-1, p);
    }
    w = 0;
    for(o=0; o<=u-x; o++)                     // Main O(w*e*u*v) matching process
        for(p=0; p<=v-y; p++) {
            t=1;
            for(c=0; c<x; c++)
                for(d=0; d<y; d++)
                if(s[c][d]*(s[c][d]-g[c+o][d+p]))
                    t=0;
            w+=t;
        }
}
```